# Importing a return value in Python

Tags: python

I have the following function in a file named contacts.py.

```
def analytics_dict(parameters: dict) -> dict:
    github_repo, ending = parameters.get("BP_FILE").split(
        "/blob/"
    )
    github_sha, gearsfile = ending.split("/")
    github_url, github_repo_name, github_org_name = github_repo.rsplit("/", 2)
    return {
        "name": parameters.get("BP_NAME"),
        "deployment_gearsfile_url": parameters.get("BP_FILE"),
        "github_org_name": github_org_name,
    }
```

I need to use the "name" value in a different file named department.py.
I am doing an import in department.py file as

```
from department import analytics_dict as analytics

candidate_name = analytics_dict.get("name")
```

I see an error -  `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'`

Can someone please let me know the right way to import the value?

Comment: As you've shown it, your code shouldn't give you that error; it should be giving an `ImportError` or `NameError` instead. Your module is named `contacts` but you're importing from `department`. And you import the function as `analytics`, then try to refer to it as `analytics_dict`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the function to get the dict:

```
candidate = analytics_dict()
```

and then you can access the `name` inside the dict:

```
candidate_name = candidate['name']
```

You can also do it all in one line as long as each individual piece (the function call and the dictionary lookup) is there in the right order:

```
candidate_name = analytics_dict()['name']
```

Comment: Note: you didn't include the entire `analytics_dict` function definition so I'm not sure if it has any required arguments.  If so, you will need to provide those as well.

Comment: I just noticed that the first line got truncated by stackoverflow. Here is the first line:

def analytics_dict(parameters: dict) -> dict:

Comment: In that case when you call `analytics_dict` you need to provide the `parameters` that tell the function where the github repo etc are.